# How remove fragment from string

Tags: c

how remove fragment from string in c?

For example:

```
int main()
{
  char *string = "Qwertyuio pasdf ghjklzxcv bnm";
  char *fragment = "pasdf";
}
```

How cut pasdf but save other?

Comment: There is no way to modify the string pointed to by `string`.

Comment: Obey the `const`...

Comment: Suggest `char string[] = "Qwertyuio pasdf ghjklzxcv bnm";` and the use of `strstr` and `memmove`.

Comment: First make a copy.

Comment: @DeiDei: A sting literal is not `const` qualified.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you cannot change the content of `string`.

Here's how to do it properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
  char *string = strdup("Qwertyuio |pasdf| ghjklzxcv bnm");
  char *fragment = "pasdf";
  char *w = string;
  int length = strlen(string);

  printf("%s\n", string);
  while (*w)
    {
      if (!strncmp(w, fragment, strlen(fragment)))
        {
          length -= strlen(fragment);
          memmove(w, w + strlen(fragment), length);
        }
      else
        {
          w++;
          length--;
        }
    }
  *w = 0;
  printf("%s\n", string);
  free(string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why strdup when you could just put it on the stack?  Also if you want to strdup you should free, although yes technically in this example the program is terminating so it doesn't matter, if the code snippet is used elsewhere it will matter.

Comment: You're right missimer, but I didn't try to produce a production-ready code, I just want to present a solution so that Arvindsinc2 can understand how to do it and adapt this to his/her real needs.